# Adding Tags to Coordinates of Images with Correct Position, Using React and Next.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I'm trying to get the coordinates of the image so I can add tags to it. I'm able to add the tag, but when I expand the browser, the tag doesn't follow to the correct position of the image. When browser gets expanded, or scaled down, the image scales correctly with the aspect ratio, however, the tag stays in the current place of the browser (not at the correct place of the image). However, if I scroll, it does move to the correct area, but that's only if scrolling occurs.

```
const initialPosition = {
  x: "",
  y: "",
};
const MediaPage = ({ user, mediaId }) => {
  const [tagPosition, setTagPosition] = useState(initialPosition);

  const imageWrapRef = createRef();

  const handleTagClick = (e) => {
    const { left, top } = imageWrapRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    const x = e.pageX - left;
    const y = e.pageY - top;
    setTagPosition((prev) => ({ ...prev, x, y }));
  };

  return (
    <div
      onClick={(e) => handleTagClick(e)}
      ref={imageWrapRef}
    >
      <div
        style={{
          left: `${tagPosition.x}px`,
          top: `${tagPosition.y}px`,
          zIndex: 2,
          padding: 10,
          position: "absolute",
       }}
      >
        1
      </div>
      <Image
        onLoad={handleLoadingComplete}
        className="w-full"
        alt=""
        src="URL"
        layout="responsive"
        width={700}
        height={800}
      />
    </div>
}
```

So essentially, I'm trying to click on an image, and then a tag will appear. However, I need to be able to set the tag on the correct position of the image, even if it scales.

Comment: You should wrap tags and image in a parent container and apply responsive styles to it, not to the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, and it was an easy fix. Had to set parent div to relative position, and then update x and y for %

```
const x = ((e.clientX - left) / width) * 100;
const y = ((e.clientY - top) / height) * 100;
```

Then in the styling:

```
left: `${tagPosition.x}%`,
top: `${tagPosition.y}%`,
```